# Apple rejected app: 5.2.2 Legal, Intellectual Property - Third Party Sites/Services

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I've developed an app for a client. It's a simple webview app showing the clients news website in the app and allowing the client to send push notifications with news to the users.

The app got rejected for the following reasons:

> Guideline 5.2.2 - Legal
>
> Your app contains content or features that may infringe upon rights
>   owned by news and media outlet, {CLIENT SITE NAME}.
>
> Your app and its contents should not infringe upon the rights of
>   another party. In the event your app infringes another party’s rights,
>   you are responsible for any liability to Apple because of a claim.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please attach documentary evidence in the App
>   Review Information section in App Store Connect. In accordance with
>   section 3.2(f) of the Apple Developer Program License Agreement, you
>   acknowledge that submitting falsified or fraudulent documentation can
>   result in the termination of your Apple Developer Program account and
>   the removal of your apps from the App Store. Once Legal has reviewed
>   your documentation and confirms its validity, we will proceed with the
>   review of your app.
>
> Alternatively, please remove the third-party content from your app and
>   its metadata.
>
> Please see attached screenshots for details.
>
> Since your App Store Connect status is Rejected, a new binary will be
>   required.

What information or documentation can I send to Apple as "documentary evidence" to prove authorization from my Client?

Comment: How about a signed letter from a representative of the client on the client's letterhead?

Comment: Good question dude, the same situation i have. Thanks for help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a legal question about policy compliance, not about programming as defined by the [help]. Legal questions can be asked on https://law.stackexchange.com/, instead.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to get an evidence of rights from your client. Get a document signed by your client and attach in Review Section. Below is the format of document :

> Hi iTunes Team,
>
> This is to state that **{ Name/Company name of client }** has authorized **{ Your Name/Company name of developer account }** for its Mobile Application development and deployment.
>
> **{ Your Name/Company name of developer account }**  has all the rights to publish the app under the name of **{ Name/Company name of client }**
>
> Please treat this document as a proof which indicates our rights.
>
> Thank you in anticipation
>
> ( Signature Here )
>
> ( Name and designation of the above Signed )

Comment: Thank you!
I've created a document for my client based on your comment and if this works I will accept your answer.

Comment: The app has been accepted and released. Thanks for your help @Vikas

Comment: Currently, I am getting this same issue and was thinking to have some kind of singed document from client. But then following is one of the note added bu iTunes team **"Note that submitting documentation showing permission to publish this app on behalf of the content owner or institution will not resolve this issue. This app must be submitted under the content owner’s own Apple Developer account."**   Please suggest.

Comment: @linrud can you please help what you created and worked for you?

Comment: Hi, what if I owns the company and still got rejection. How to tell apple about that I am the owner.

Comment: @lincolnerson Hi, have you found solution? i am also stuck with this note

Comment: @linrud Could you please share the document? I am stuck in this rejection and I really need your help.

Comment: For anyone having this issue, just copy the text in the answer to a document, change the placeholders, print it, get it signed, scan it and attach it when submitting the app to Apple.

Comment: @DucNguyen same problem, How can i contact with you?

Comment: So Do I need to print it and get the sign by hand. I copied this form and apple continue reject with the same issue